# Spring Tools 4, Java 11, Tomcat 9, Spring 5 app - runs in regular mode but hangs indefinitely when trying to debug

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite, tomcat9, spring-tools-4

No breakpoint sets, fresh install (yesterday) of Spring Tools 4, using MS Open JDK 11, Tomcat 9 and Spring 5. My webapp starts up fine on Tomcat if I run it regular but when I try to run in debug mode it just hangs indefinitely. No breakpoints are set. Is there an argument I need to set in Tomcat, STS  or Java in order to get it to run in Debug mode?

Update based on comment for more info:
I'm using Spring Tool Suite 4. I've added Tomcat 9 as a Server via the IDE options (Window->Show View->Servers, then right click in window and adding Tomcat 9).  I've started debug by right clicking on the server and selecting Debug and also through he debug icon in the top menu of STS.  I have tried switching JREs from the one I installed (Java 11) to the default one that came with STS (Java 17) and that did not make a difference. I was able to run a basic Java class in debug mode so I feel like that has ruled out STS and Java as the issues and now I'm focusing on Tomcat (Tomcat 9) and the web app (Spring 5) itself and trying to see if there are any configuration options that I need to make.

Comment: How are you running in debug mode?   Using an IDE?  From the command line?   Please provide any details that might help us understand and diagnose your problem.

Comment: @StephenC - I've updated the question with more details.